Wordpress dynamic list of companies
I work in WordPress and need to create a page where various employers can add their company using a form. If approved, the company will automatically be added to the website in the list of companies. I would like to know if there is a plugin or something that can handle this automatic addition. Basically, something like a directory of companies with contact details.
